# How to start/stop a Broadband connection at a specific time on Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-7, automation, broadband

I want to start my broadband connection at a specific time, and stop it at specific time. How do I achieve it on Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to disable your network adapter via the task scheduler, then just enable it again when you choose.
You can also run a batch script to change your IP configuration, you'd use the task scheduler for this as well.

EDIT: There are also programs like [K9 Web Protection](http://www.k9webprotection.com) that can block web access on a specified schedule.